# List of Previous Pages on Flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-getx

How can I know the list of previous pages in flutter, I'm using getx for navigation

I didn't tried anything.
.

static void checkForRootLink() {

```
//get currenmt page of the app

log('Current route:${Get.currentRoute}');

log(RuntimeConfigs.routeObserver!.routeStack.toString());

// if (currentRoute == NamedRoutes.socialAppHomeIndex.path) {

//   //Already in home screen

//   //No need to do anything

// }

// // else if (Get.route) {

// //}

// else {

//   CustomRouting.replaceStackWithNamed(NamedRoutes.splashIndex.path);

//   // CustomRouting.popUntil(

//   //   NamedRoutes.root.path,

//   // );

// }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution

Create a route observer file and paste the below code. Add the instance of route observer inside GetmaterailApp.

```js
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RouteStackObserver extends NavigatorObserver {
  final List<String> routeStack = [];

  @override
  void didPush(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    if (route.settings.name != null) {
      // Adding the route to the stack when a new route is pushed.
      log('RouteStack before push : $routeStack');
      routeStack.add(route.settings.name!);
      log('RouteStack after push : $routeStack');
    }
  }

  @override
  void didPop(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    if (previousRoute != null && previousRoute.settings.name != null) {
      // Removing the last route from the stack when a route is popped.
      log('RouteStack before popped: $routeStack');
      routeStack.removeLast();
      log('RouteStack after popped: $routeStack');
    }
  }

  @override
  void didRemove(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    if (route.settings.name != null) {
      // Removing a specific route from the stack when it is removed.
      log('RouteStack before removed: $routeStack');
      routeStack.remove(route.settings.name);
      log('RouteStack after removed: $routeStack');
    }
  }

  @override
  void didReplace({Route<dynamic>? newRoute, Route<dynamic>? oldRoute}) {
    if (newRoute != null && newRoute.settings.name != null) {
      // Replacing the last route in the stack with the new route.
      log('RouteStack before replaced: $routeStack');
      if (routeStack.isNotEmpty) {
        routeStack.removeLast();
      }
      routeStack.add(newRoute.settings.name!);
      log('RouteStack after replaced: $routeStack');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same by using
[https://pub.dev/documentation/navigation_history_observer/latest/#:~:text=To%20access%20the%20history%2C%20use,would%20be%20the%20current%20route.](https://pub.dev/documentation/navigation_history_observer/latest/#:%7E:text=To%20access%20the%20history%2C%20use,would%20be%20the%20current%20route.)